# Appropriateness of seeding an identification question

Tags: discussion, story-identification

I was about to ask a TV series identification question that I'd had for years. I tried one last bout of googling, and after varying keywords quite a bit, I found a candidate title, which didn't look very promising from the context but nonetheless turned out to be right.

Would it be appropriate for me to post the question? I have the answer now, so I would give the answer as well. Normally I wouldn't consider this a problem, but for identification questions it's hard to judge whether my question and answer would help other people.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without seeing the question, it is hard to say whether it is appropriate. Sometimes it is better to include your (hypothetical) question here to help provide context.

But, in the general sense, seeding *can* be okay…sometimes. Sometimes not. It is not generally encouraged, unless the question is one that will provide *really* good content. Don't seed simply for the sake of adding bulk to the site. That is not what you want for this site.

I wrote more about this issue here: [**Asking the First Questions**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/).

Answer (score 4):

An interesting question, on the first few days of the site I asked a few questions I knew I could figure out, but I legitimately didn't know.  Though many of those questions caught some negative attention from the moderators (I still want a good answer to a couple!!11).
There's not much of a fine line between these two different ways to "fake" a question.

The only problem I see is that some might abuse this to ask really bad questions.  On the other-hand that's what the down-vote and close-vote are for.

The site could really use more questions, but we also need to maintain quality.